# Record with operations on a list Java

Tags: java, list, record

I have a class MyList,in Java, with some basics operations like add,get and remove.Also in my list I must have a record with operations which have done with the list.How I can do this record?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a new class atribute. It can be a String. Like this:

```
public MyList{
private String record;
....
}
```

Then on each of your methods you update this atribute:

```
record += "\n"+*the operation*;
```

But if you want a better performance, you should use a StringBuffer instead of a String ([see here](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Flang%2FStringBuffer.html&ei=p-JwU9OyPOveygPsnYDQCQ&usg=AFQjCNG5XTLXH8LdknmZ1Ql61aXa8Bf6uQ&sig2=bsjvodKImPIfdmk9x1zhzg&bvm=bv.66330100,d.bGQ&cad=rjt)).

Was this the answer that you wanted?

Comment: This is the problem ---Create a custom list backed by an integer array that accepts strings as its values. Additionally the list must keep a record of all the operations and be able to return this information upon request.

Comment: @user3628986 how do you want to accede and view this records? by the date the operation occured? or other?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you want to keep track of updates made to MyList in order to have an history of what has been done.

Why not creating a ListHistory class

```
public class ListHistory {
    private Action action;
    private Object data;

    public ListHistory(Action action, Object data) {
        this.action = action;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and the Action enum type (so you can make it evolve)

```
public enum Action {
    get, add, remove;
}
```

and define a `private List<ListHistory> history;` variable to keep track of updates ?

You then have the ability to manipulate the history list as you want, add date to ListHistory if needed (or use a `Map<Date, ListHistory>`)

Hope this will help.

regards,

Yann